# Changing CPU power usage in WinXP

Tags: cpu, power-management, cooling

I have Win7 and an overheating processor. In normal circumstances, I can set the power usage (customizing Power options in control panel) to 80% (or whichever percentage I want) and then it does not overheat.

However, I am now switching to better processor, but I want to leave this one running WinXP on another computer. However, WinXP does not have any such option in control panel, so my question is this:

Is there any program that can limit processor usage to some specific percentage just as Win7 does through control panel.

(please do not answer with: "check your cooling" or something like that. I just need to know if there is such a program.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an AMD Processor you can try out Phenom MSR Twear
http://phenommsrtweake.sourceforge.net/

You can also look at your motherboards software, it's normally bundled with an application that can provide power usage options for your CPU.

If not, you can underclock your CPU in the BIOS, that's one other way around it.

Comment: I don't have Phenom, so the first advice does not apply. But I had lowered the voltage from default 1.35 to 1.15 and clock from 200x11 to 200x9 and now during the stress test with both cores at 100% it never goes above 54 °C. And even that was after almost half an hour of stress testing.

Comment: I would consider that safe if it was running for 30 mins, although my Phenom II @ 1.5v doesn't go above 50c, Do you have Speedstep enabled? Another power saving option you could use.